# Android - admob banner crashes when setting back to visible

Tags: android, crash, admob

I'm displaying a SMART BANNER at the top of my game but only want it displayed in the frontend.

Upon entering the game I call:

```
GameMainActivity.mAdView.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
```

This works find and the game continues until the player dies. Then I call:

```
GameMainActivity.mAdView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
```

Then it crashes. Is there more to it than what I've done here?

EDIT: logcat as follows:

02-07 18:44:22.422  19564-19674/com.onesevenone.simples E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Game Thread
    Process: com.onesevenone.simples, PID: 19564
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:902)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4637)
            at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11690)
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11654)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9616)
            at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6663)
            at com.onesevenone.game.state.GameState.update(GameState.java:63)
            at com.onesevenone.simples.GameView.updateAndRender(GameView.java:100)
            at com.onesevenone.simples.GameView.run(GameView.java:120)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: show logcat stack trace when app crashing

Comment: you are calling `GameMainActivity.mAdView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);` from non UI Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're making the call from non UI Thread. You can run on the UI Thread using the [runOnUiThread(Runnable action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method:

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GameMainActivity.mAdView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```